# foreach user subfolder

Tags: powershell

I need to get to a certain file for each username on our user share:

```
\\\server\share\username\windows\application Data\MICROSOFT\Proof\custom.dic
```

How do I code `foreach` to get me from the root past each username?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem \\computerName\share | ?{$_.PsIsContainer} | %{$localDir='c:\localDir'}{Copy-Item "\\computerName\share\$($_.Name)\a.txt" "$localDir\$($_.Name)_a.txt"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a wildcard for the username:

```
Get-ChildItem '\\server\share\*\windows\application Data\MICROSOFT\Proof\custom.dic'
```